# Angualrjs: How to manage showing cascaded select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this models:

```
var data = [
   {
     id: 1,
     level:1,
     name:"X1",
     subChildren:[{
                id:3,
                level:2,
                name:"X1-1",
                subChildren:[...]
              }]
},
{
     id: 2,
     level:1,
     name:"X2",
     subChildren:[{
                id:4,
                level:2,
                name:"X2-2",
                subChildren:[...]
              }]
}....];

var levels=[{ level:1,.. },{ level:2,.. },...];
```

What I want is to show the data in html `<select>` element, and cascade them depending on the selected parent. i.e:

```html
level 1:
<select>
  <option>X1</option>
  <option>X2</option>
</select>

-
level 2: (subChildren)
<select>
  <option>X1-1</option>
</select>

-
level 3 (sub subChildren)
<select>
  <option>X1-1-1</option>
</select>
```

This is only a non-functional demonstration for what I want to show, when you choose one of the parents it will cascade the next `<select>` which should be the next level (and contains the sub children) and so on..
The problem is I don't know the number of `levels` or the number of `parents` or `subChildren`, it's all dynamic, and don't know how to do this without writing a lot of native code.
The whole idea is I want to iterate over `levels` array and create the `<select>` tags.

Comment: Check this out: http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates

Answer (score 0):

This solution works only if you know the maximum number of subchildren you will encounter.Please check the plunkr [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/183G10cHYIOedvjQZzo3?p=preview)

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('Dropdown', []).controller('DpdController', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    id: 1,
    level: 1,
    name: "X1",
    subChildren: [{
      id: 3,
      level: 2,
      name: "X1-1",
      subChildren: [{
        id: 4,
        level: 3,
        name: "X1-2"
      }]
    }]
  }];
  $scope.logValue = function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Dropdown">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="DpdController">
  <select name="repeatSelect" id="repeatSelect" ng-model="selectedValue" ng-change="logValue(selectedValue)" ng-options="option.name for option in data">
  </select>
  <span ng-if='selectedValue'>
         <select name="repeatSelect1" id="repeatSelect1" ng-model="selectedValue1"
         ng-change="logValue(selectedValue1)"
         ng-options="option.name for option in selectedValue.subChildren">
      </select>
    </span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is fixed, I want the same thing but dynamically built.